# GAE devappserver2 TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.datetime' and 'NoneType'

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I've seen many iterations of this question, and many pretty specific and useless ansers. The question is something like:

When running `dev_appserver.py app.yaml` I get an error like so:

```
waxed_backend_1        | _run_file(__file__, globals())
waxed_backend_1        |   File "/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py", line 97, in _run_file
waxed_backend_1        |     execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)
waxed_backend_1        |   File "/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 899, in <module>
waxed_backend_1        |     main()
waxed_backend_1        |   File "/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 895, in main
waxed_backend_1        |     dev_server.stop()
waxed_backend_1        |   File "/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 775, in stop
waxed_backend_1        |     metrics.GetMetricsLogger().Stop()
waxed_backend_1        |   File "/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/metrics.py", line 123, in Stop
waxed_backend_1        |     total_run_time = int((Now() - self._start_time).total_seconds())
waxed_backend_1        | TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.datetime' and 'NoneType'
```

How does one debug this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the metrics.py script mentioned in the error you'll see something like this:

```
class _MetricsLogger(object):
  """Logs metrics for the devappserver to Google Analytics."""

  def __init__(self):
    """Initializes a _MetricsLogger."""
    self._client_id = None
    self._user_agent = None
    self._runtimes = None
    self._start_time = None
    self._log_once_on_stop_events = {}

  def Start(self, client_id, user_agent=None, runtimes=None):
    """Starts a Google Analytics session for the current client.

    Args:
      client_id: A string Client ID representing a unique anonyized user.
      user_agent: A string user agent to send with each log.
      runtimes: A set of strings containing the runtimes used.
    """
    self._start_time = Now()
    self._client_id = client_id
    self._user_agent = user_agent
    self._runtimes = ','.join(sorted(list(runtimes))) if runtimes else None
    self.Log(DEVAPPSERVER_CATEGORY, START_ACTION)

  def Stop(self):
    """Ends a Google Analytics session for the current client."""

    total_run_time = int((Now() - self._start_time).total_seconds())   ###### <<<<< ERROR HERE

    self.LogOnceOnStop(DEVAPPSERVER_CATEGORY, STOP_ACTION, value=total_run_time)
    self.LogBatch(self._log_once_on_stop_events.itervalues()) 

etc
```

`_start_time` was initialised to None and was never updated. This is because some exception was raised before `Start` was called. And then gae ate our traceback. Nom nom.

So to debug this error the best thing is to retrieve our traceback. i just edited my metrics.py Stop function to look like so:

```
  def Stop(self):
    """Ends a Google Analytics session for the current client."""
    import traceback
    sErr = traceback.format_exc()
    if sErr:
      print(sErr)
      print('===========')

    total_run_time = int((Now() - self._start_time).total_seconds())

    self.LogOnceOnStop(DEVAPPSERVER_CATEGORY, STOP_ACTION, value=total_run_time)
    self.LogBatch(self._log_once_on_stop_events.itervalues())
```

Now it prints out the traceback of the original error

Comment: For other people that are finding this thread: @Sheena is correct that it means that an error was thrown before `_start_time` was initiated and in my case it was the the app.yaml didn't have the right format/necessary values. This will cause dev_appserver.py to fail before starting correctly. Check you `app.yaml`.

Comment: @Mathias I've gotten this error from a few different things. Usually because of errors in the Python code, not the yaml. While I do think that errors can come up in the configuration that's just one of many places to look. The best place to look to figure out an exception is usually the traceback. Otherwise it's a matter of checking what you edited since your last run and then digging through that. Which is no fun at all most of the time